# Running maven integration tests with docker-maven-plugin in Jenkins

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins

I have a maven project that usese the io.fabric8 docker-maven-plugin to launch a database as part of my integration tests. When I run the integration tests locally it works, but when run on my Jenkins server I get an error saying there is no `DOCKER_HOST` variable.

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.20.1:start (prepare-itdatabase) on project myproject: Execution prepare-itdatabase of goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.20.1:start failed: No <dockerHost> given, no DOCKER_HOST environment variable, no read/writable '/var/run/docker.sock' or '//./pipe/docker_engine' and no external provider like Docker machine configured -> [Help 1]`

It might be worth mentioning that my Jenkins instance itself is launched through docker, by simply using something like `docker run jenkins`.

I tried to set the `DOCKER_HOST` variable to `tcp://192.168.59.103:2375` when starting Jenkins, but that just caused it to time out in the build.

Comment: there are some examples on how to run docker in docker (dind) already. mainly you need to tell your docker container to use the docker from its host (havent tried it, just to show the idea): docker run --rm --user root --name myjenkins -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins

Comment: I did that thanks! My problem now is however that my tests (running in the jenkins docker) cant connect to the mysql docker on 127.0.0.1. It did not help to run the jenkins docker with --net="host".

Comment: I think with multiple containers needed to be running vor a test you're better off using docker-compose as it lets you link containers by their name not messing with most of the networking yourself

Comment: The problem with docker-compose is that it means that I have to change my maven files (if even possible?). I would like to make use of the docker-maven plugin to launch the dependencies needed by my test to run.

Comment: the plugin version you use might not include that but the current version (0.24.0) has some support for compose: https://dmp.fabric8.io/#docker-compose - if you prefer configuring the setup in xml or the compose yaml files - both should be possible with that plugin. I just find compose files more readable that generate it out of the plugin xml config.

Answer (score 0):

> my Jenkins instance itself is launched through docker, by simply using something like docker run jenkins

I assume you run your build directly on the Jenkins master of your container (no slave). Your build process run inside the container, which does not have Docker binary or socket installed.

You'll have to mount the Docker socket in your container and install the Docker binaries. [This blog post explains things in details](https://getintodevops.com/blog/the-simple-way-to-run-docker-in-docker-for-ci), in short what you can do is:

Launch your Jenkins container with Docker socket:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --name jenkins \
  jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

And install Docker inside the container. Said blog post gives a handy script to be run inside the container:

```
apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
     ca-certificates \
     curl \
     gnupg2 \
     software-properties-common && \
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg > /tmp/dkey; apt-key add /tmp/dkey && \
add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable" && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install docker-ce
```

You can run this script by-hand or as part of your Jenkins build. From now-on you should be able to run Docker commands from inside your container (and in your builds).

Alternatively, you can configure a Jenkins Slave independently from your Master and have Docker installed on this Slave.

Comment: This is already what I am doing. The issue is that when I run my tests (a java program executing inside the Jenkins docker), it is not able to connect to the mysql docker (launched by the test) since the mysql docker actually is not running inside the Jenkins docker, but as a sibbling to the Jenkins docker. My question is really how I can make it connect and expose the mysql docker inside the Jenkins docker.

Comment: I believe the problem from your initial question is solved ;) (thanks to @wemu apparently), you are now able to launch your tests from your Jenkins container. Linking your Mysql and Jenkins container is a different issue, try looking in Docker networking to link both containers. You should post another question for this specific issue by describing the situation (otherwise that may cause confusion as your initial question would not be related to the given answer). Feel free to comment the new question link here I'll be happy to help.